# How to format date in list?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to format a list of dates? I tried formatting it by formatting the list but got an error..

The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.

```
    var list = <DateTime>[];
    DateTime start = DateTime(2018, 12, 30);
    final end = DateTime(2022, 12, 31);

    while (start.isBefore(end)) {
      list.add(start);
      start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }

    print(DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(list)); // The argument type 'List<DateTime>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.
```

When I format the date before it's put in a list an error comes up saying you can't use isBefore on a string.

```
   var list = <DateTime>[];
    DateTime start = DateTime(2018, 12, 30);
    var date = DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(start);
    final end = DateTime(2022, 12, 31);

    while (date.isBefore(end)) { //The method 'isBefore' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
      list.add(start);
      start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first code snippet to the following code:

```
    var list = <String>[];
    DateTime start = DateTime(2018, 12, 30);
    final end = DateTime(2022, 12, 31);

    while (start.isBefore(end)) {
     var formatedData = DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(start)
      list.add(formatedData);
      start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
```

Since [`format()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat/format.html) method returns a `String` then change the list to type `String` and then inside the while loop, you can format the `start` date and add it to the list.